# Setup fullwidth backgrounds to bootstrap columns which still need to keep the page container aligment rules

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

There are two columns (second one is separated with other two columns ). I need to setup backgrounds to each of them, but the text still need to follow the side page alingment. I'm using Bootstrap. http://www.screencast.com/t/0YxmYlE76

Comment: can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I fixed the problem.

```
.col-sm-8 {
    height: 600px
}

.col-sm-8:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 66vw;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to replicate the screenshot provided with your question? If so in order to set a background image to each column you will need:

```
.div {
   background-image:url(/path/to/image);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center top;
   background-size: cover; //this will ensure the background image always covers the width of the div
   height: 500px; //change this to whatever height you want to set
   text-align:left; //to align text to the left of the div
}
```

The above is one way of writing the CSS, you could use shorthand for the background image styles like below which is a less long winded way of writing the styles in your stylesheet:

```
.div {
   background: url(/path/to/image) no-repeat center top;
   background-position: cover;
   height: 500px;
   text-align:left;
}
```

Also note if you are building a responsive site, you can change the height for the div across different breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the layout in your screen shot using bootstrap, you can use something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/rejw439u/

HTML layout would look like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8"><h1>The Contingent Workforce</h1></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="col-xs-12"><h2>Heading 2 Article</h2></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12"><h2>Heading 2 Article</h2></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can then add classes like my fiddle link to add background styling etc.

Comment: I'm not sure did you understand me well, it's ok with the images, but I need to keep the content alignment withing the main container dimensions and to be aligned with the rest content in the page. In your solution, this is not the case.